# wp7:how to check in if condition progressbar is visible or not?

Tags: windows-phone-7, if-statement, progress-bar

I have one progress bar and i want check contion is like that

```
if( StkProgressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible)
{
    //coding
}
else
{

}
```

But if condition give error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Visibility' to 'bool'

How can i solve this problem?
Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( StkProgressbar.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
{
  //U used '=' instead of '==' :)
}
```